# Creating a hexplot

Tags: r, matlab, matplotlib, gnuplot, matlab-figure

I am trying to create a figure like the one depicted in the third column of the following image:

[image]

[Link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuOrR.jpg) in case of backup.

Basically I have x and y positions of 200 particles and I have the MSD data for these 200 positions. I'd like MSD to be the value that should determine a color map for the particles in coordinates `(x,y)`. So MSD should be like the height, or the `z` position corresponding to each particle in `(x,y)`.

I am surprised at my incompetence, because I have been trying to solve this problem for the last couple of days but none of the Google searches gave me any result. The closest thing that I have found is the concept of "self-organizing map" in Matlab and R, but I do not know how to use R and Matlab's toolbox for SOM was utterly useful for my needs.

I tried the following code in Matlab and get the attached plot as a result:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

x = (dlmread('xdata.dat'))'; % x is 1x200 array
y = (dlmread('ydata.dat'))'; % y is 1x200 array 
msd = (dlmread('msd_field.txt'))'; % msd is 1x200 array

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = meshgrid(msd);
z = [X; Y; Z]; 
surf(z)
```

But I think this plot is not useful at all. What I want is a 2D scatter plot of `(x,y)` depicting particle positions and on top of that color code this scatter plot with the values stored in msd like the plot I showed in the beginning. How can I create this through Matlab, or any other visualization tool? Thank you in advance.

[image: Surface graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear whay you want to have. Here a scatter plot using `ggplot2`.

```
## some reproducible data 
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = round(runif(200,-30,30),2),
  y = round(runif(200,-2,30),2),
  msd = sample(c(0,2,3),200,rep=T))

## scatter plot where the size/color of points depends in msd
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y,size=msd,color=msd)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like what I need. I want to create a scatter plot of (x,y) and color code them with the values in z. All of them are 1x200 arrays. It looks like this code is written in R. I am trying to make this plot for a presentation. I will try to learn and implement this by then. Although I kinda still hope there is a way to do it in Python or Matlab as well. Thank you.

Comment: you can see [python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html). It vas the same syntax as thhis R code (maybe even easier). df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', s='msd')